# git push command for pushing a local commit to a different remote branch

Tags: android, git, repository

I synced to a repo tree which is branch "jb"... I have a local commit on this branch which I am trying to push to a remote branch "jb_mr2" and running into following error..is there a git push command which I can use to push this local commit to "jb_mr2"

```
terminal3{73}> git push ssh://company.com:29418/platform/vendor/com-proprietary/ship/ftm 72bc75e409e50dcad29bd790b4b6478dc6668f12:refs/for/jb_mr2
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 32 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 7.01 KiB, done.
Total 6 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done   
To ssh://company.com:29418/platform/vendor/com-proprietary/ship/ftm
 ! [remote rejected] 72bc75e409e50dcad29bd790b4b6478dc6668f12 -> refs/for/jb_mr2 (branch jb_mr2 not found)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://company.com:29418/platform/vendor/com-proprietary/ship/ftm'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to play with this a bit more and have a better solution. If I read you correctly, the remote branch "jb_mr2" already exists. From the local branch with the commits run this:

```
git push ssh://company.com:29418/platform/vendor/com-proprietary/ship/ftm 72bc75e409e50dcad29bd790b4b6478dc6668f12:jb_mr2
```

If the remote does not exist:

```
git push ssh://company.com:29418/platform/vendor/com-proprietary/ship/ftm 72bc75e409e50dcad29bd790b4b6478dc6668f12:/refs/heads/jb_mr2
```

Comment: Whew... took some fighting with the code, but I believe this works properly now in both instances.