# How to push several local commits in local branch A into remote branch B and clear them from local branch A?

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging

I had some branch checked out locally. I committed a fist full och changes to it. Just when I was about to push them to the remote repo, I realized, I was working on the wrong branch.

I need to sort of 'move' those commits to the other branch, both locally and remotely, that is:

I have:

- local branch A plus changes (commited, not pushed),
- local branch B no changes,
- currently checked out local branch A
- remote branche A no changes,
- remote branch B no changes

And I need to end up with:

- local branch A no changes,
- local branch B plus changes (pushed),
- remote branch A no changes,
- remote branch B plus changes.

I am new to git and not a professional developer, so git-push(1) does not help me without further research.

I came across this post: [git push command for pushing a local commit to a different remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982791/git-push-command-for-pushing-a-local-commit-to-a-different-remote-branch)

It suggests:

```
git push ssh://company.com:29418/platform/vendor/com-proprietary/ship/ftm 72bc75e409e50dcad29bd790b4b6478dc6668f12:jb_mr2
```

Obviously the `jb_mr2`-part I change to whatever my branch B is called, but where do I get the rest of the numbers, and by what means do I get rid of the changes on branch A?

Comment: A friend helped me, we figured it out:

Comment: A friend helped me, we figured it out:

```
$(A) git log
- 1236
more new files need to check
- 1235
new files need to check
- 1234
checked files ready for project
$(A) git checkout B
$(B) git cherry-pick 1235, 1236
$(B) git checkout A
$(A) git reset --hard 1234
```

Obviously the numbers are much longer and not in sequence since they are checksums.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move the most recent commit(s) to a new branch with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git)

Comment: Here's an good answer to this type of question ('how do I move commits from one branch to another'): https://stackoverflow.com/a/36463546/20371

Comment: Thanks, Yawar, I didn't come across that thread in my research, but that seems correct (only I already have that other branch). Anyway, I fixed my problem this time, but I'll bookmark that answer, because I'm pretty sure I WILL forget to switch branches some time soon again, possibly with more commits than the few I had now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend helped me, we figured it out:

```
$(A) git log 
- 1236 more new files need to check 
- 1235 new files need to check 
- 1234 checked files ready for project 
$(A) git checkout B 
$(B) git cherry-pick 1235
$(B) git cherry-pick 1236 
$(B) git checkout A 
$(A) git reset --hard 1234
```

Obviously the numbers are much longer and not in sequence since they are checksums.

This worked fine for me, as I had *only a few commits* to take care of. And they were the *last commits* in sequence.

If there were later commits that should not be moved or if there had been lots of commits, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git/36463546#36463546) that Yawar referred to above seems worth checking out.